# How to add Gradle to an existing project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have an existing project in Android Studio that I originally imported from Eclipse.

I haven't been using any specific build system to build my project other than the one provided by default with the Android Studio IDE (though the project was originally created with Eclipse.

I haven't been able to find a good tutorial of the steps. What's the recommended approach to add Gradle to this project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: AndroidStudio takes care to create it for you when you import a *not android studio* project

Comment: @Blackbelt And what about to an already imported project?

Comment: Good point. You could create a new project from scratch and import your source code folder..

Comment: I would prefer the approach of just adding Gradle if is possible. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @ManuelEscrig This question doesn't really make sense. Android Studio/Intellij runs on top of Gradle. If you add a "module" to your "project", make sure you have it in your `settings.gradle` and it can now be built with Gradle.

Comment: @JaredBurrows So you're telling me there is no option for adding Gradle to an existing project w/o Gradle in Android Studio?

Comment: The whole point of using Android Studio/Intellij is for Gradle. Why are you trying to run a project in Android Studio and not use Gradle? That is very counter intuitive.

Comment: @JaredBurrows We're trying to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse because it is a project that we have to export a few times a day and with Eclipse we're having random errors when exporting and with Android Studio none.

Comment: @ManuelEscrig This getting to be completely unclear what you are asking. You can build that "eclipse" project with Android Studio or Intellij.

Comment: @JaredBurrows What I'm asking is "How to add Gradle to an existing project in Android Studio?"

Comment: I have answered your question. `Android Studio/Intellij runs on top of Gradle. If you add a "module" to your "project", make sure you have it in your settings.gradle and it can now be built with Gradle.`

Comment: @JaredBurrows Where?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new project in android studio as the folder structure used by gradle is different than the one used by eclipse. Then copy the files into their matching folder.

Here is a detailed description about the folder structure: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html